# mysql doesn't show result if the query option has empty record in one of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables that store data for my wife application.

I don't have a problem to load the profile from customer table if there is a record from services table.

But mysql code doesn't work if query customer record that don't have a record in services table.

here is mysql code:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer, services
WHERE customer.cust_id = services.customer_id
AND customer.slug  LIKE 'john-doe'
AND services.deleted = '0'
```

it work perfect for `john-doe` as it show all record for both customer and services table but
if i change **john-doe** to **jeff-chew** it show record count 0.

What I trying to achieve is using the same query code for my profile view page.

If there is a services record for this customer, it show display all the record from services table, else if there is no services record found in the services table, it should show only profile data from customer table.

here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83871b/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a left outer join:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c left outer join
     services s
     ON c.cust_id = s.customer_id and s.delete = '0'
WHERE c.slug LIKE 'john-doe';
```

A simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.  They are not needed.  You should always use explicit `join` syntax, which is more expressive anyway (it handles outer joins, for instance).

Also, I added table aliases to the query, which makes it easier to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left join`.  Remember that columns from the `left join` table are `null` if no match was found:

```
select  *
from    customer c
left join
        services s
on      s.customer_id = c.cust_id
        and s.deleted = '0'
where   c.slug  LIKE 'john-doe'
```

Comment: it works, but `AND services.deleted = '0'` this was removed, I need this code as well as it only load the record that didn't deleted.

Comment: The `services.deleted = '0'` is in the `on` clause.  That means it will only find services that are not deleted.  If you put it in the `where` clause, it will filter out customers without a service as well, because `deleted` is `null` in their case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
That use left join, that gives you all records, hat haven't a record in the other table.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer left join services on customer.cust_id = services.customer_id     AND services.deleted = '0'

where customer.slug  LIKE 'john-doe'
```

See the [official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) for more information

Comment: `where services.deleted = '0'` effectively makes this an `inner join`

Comment: @Andomar Thanks. Have changed my answer.